# Magento 2 CORS issue

Tags: magento2, cors

I have multi store as well as multi domain in my magento site.

- www.domain.nl
- www.domain.be

the issue occurs in back-end (admin grid) when I want to filter products, orders,  or customers.

the error says

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://www.domain.be/admin_12w5st/mui/index/render/key/' (redirected from 'https://www.domain.nl/admin_12w5st/mui/index/render/key/a65af72908ae41562210df6cbc370a9bf0d4ce996237d2a40aec7804fa8d3673/?namespace=customer_listing&search=&filters%5Bplaceholder%5D=true&filters%5Bentity_id%5D%5Bfrom%5D=1&filters%5Bentity_id%5D%5Bto%5D=2&paging%5BpageSize%5D=20&paging%5Bcurrent%5D=1&sorting%5Bfield%5D=entity_id&sorting%5Bdirection%5D=asc&isAjax=true') from origin 'https://www.domain.nl' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: Redirect is not allowed for a preflight request.
```

[image]

here are my environment :

- nginx
- magento 2.2.9
- php 7.0.33

I tried to put

`add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*' 'always';`
or without quote mark
`add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin *;` in my server.headers file but still no luck, the issue still persist.

Does anyone have any idea? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: then your header is missing or incomplete

Comment: @MagenX thank you for your response. what does `the header is missing` how can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

to check headers you can use Chrome extension or developer tools:

1 - [HTTP Headers](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-headers/nioieekamcpjfleokdcdifpmclkohddp)

2 - Press F12 in Chrome, then selecting Network > assets > Headers tab

full cors headers:

```
# Wide-open CORS config for nginx
 #
location / {
     if ($request_method = 'OPTIONS') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        #
        # Custom headers and headers various browsers *should* be OK with but aren't
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        #
        # Tell client that this pre-flight info is valid for 20 days
        #
        add_header 'Access-Control-Max-Age' 1728000;
        add_header 'Content-Type' 'text/plain; charset=utf-8';
        add_header 'Content-Length' 0;
        return 204;
     }
     if ($request_method = 'POST') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
     if ($request_method = 'GET') {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' '*';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Methods' 'GET, POST, OPTIONS';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Headers' 'DNT,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,Range';
        add_header 'Access-Control-Expose-Headers' 'Content-Length,Content-Range';
     }
}
```

https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/grpc/custom-cors-nginx

https://enable-cors.org/server_nginx.html

Comment: I got this error in my network tab [link](http://prntscr.com/oy40xf) I was stuck after 
couple weeks of experiencing this problem

Comment: this is very old issue, was fixed in magento 2.3.2 and incorrect nginx config.