# How to enable CORs to access Magento rest APIs : Magento2

Tags: magento2, api, nginx, angularjs

I'm getting an error while call API from **Angular** APP
**test website and app is hosted in different domain.**

- Website Url abc.test.com
- Angular App : xyz.test.com

When I call API for Listing Of product in getting below Error

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 400 ()
>   Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://abc.test.com/rest/V1/products?searchCriteria%5BpageSize%5D=10&searchCriteria%5BcurrentPage%5D=1&searchCriteria%5BsortOrders%5D%5B0%5D%5Bdirection%5D=DESC&searchCriteria%5BsortOrders%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=created_at'
>   from origin 'http://xyz.test.com' has been blocked by CORS policy:
>   Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

How to solved it?

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/286261/magento-2-cors-issue

Comment: This repository https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests might help you

Comment: Tried the above @TarekAdra but still seeing the same CORS errors. [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHv0E.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHv0E.png)

Comment: https://github.com/graycoreio/magento2-cors, this one is also good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Nginx Not pass Access-Control-Allow-Origin

by using below module it will pass the header in [API](https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests/blob/master/Plugin/CorsHeadersPlugin.php)
It can update from `Store >> Config >> General >> WEb` Change * to any url you want to access

https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests

Answer (score 2):

You may try to create a PHP script as described below and after that instead calling Magento 2 API directly from the angular app (xyz.test.com), call this PHP script with some parameter. In the PHP script, you can add **Access-Control-Allow-Origin** to the header.

It is not the best solution but works.

**step 1)**

Create a PHP file under Magento 2 root

Please change **Site Url** , **API User name** and **API Password** in the script.

**File: apiconnect.php**

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *")
$magentoSiteUrl = 'http://www.YOUR-SITE.com';
$userData = array("username" => 'A_ADMIN_USERNAME', "password" => 'A_ADMIN_PASSWORD');
define('MAGENTO_SITE_URL',$magentoSiteUrl);
$ch = curl_init($magentoSiteUrl."/index.php/rest/V1/integration/admin/token");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($userData));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Content-Lenght: " . strlen(json_encode($userData)))); 
$token = curl_exec($ch); // get access Token, use it for API call
$jobName = $_REQUEST['jobname'];

switch ($jobName){

    case 'getproducts':
     getProductsData($token);
     break; 

    default:
     echo "Not Job Name found in request";
     break;
}




function getProductsData($accToken)
{


    $searchCriteria='';
    $searchCriteria .= 'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][field]=sku&';
    $searchCriteria .= 'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][value]=ABC123&';
    $searchCriteria .= 'searchCriteria[filter_groups][0][filters][0][condition_type]=eq';

    $ch = curl_init(MAGENTO_SITE_URL."/index.php/rest/V1/products/search?".$searchCriteria);    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");    
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: application/json", "Authorization: Bearer " . json_decode($accToken)));     
    $result = curl_exec($ch);    
    echo $result;    
}
```

**step 2)**

From your angular app (xyz.test.com) access to Magento API using URL like

***www.my-magento-siteurl.com/apiconnect.php?jobname=getproducts***

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way is to add Allow origin to your **.htaccess** in home directory 
into your .htacess search for

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>
```

and insert the follwing code :

```
SetEnvIf Accept application/json API
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" env=API
Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization" env=API
```

your .htaccess file will be look like this at the end :

```
<IfModule mod_headers.c>

    Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=edge"

    SetEnvIf Accept application/json API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Methods "POST, GET, OPTIONS, DELETE, PUT" env=API
    Header always set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Origin, Accept, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Access-Control-Request-Method, Access-Control-Request-Headers, Authorization" env=API

    # `mod_headers` cannot match based on the content-type, however,
    # the `X-UA-Compatible` response header should be send only for
    # HTML documents and not for the other resources.

    <FilesMatch "\.(appcache|atom|bbaw|bmp|crx|css|cur|eot|f4[abpv]|flv|geojson|gif|htc|ico|jpe?g|js|json(ld)?|m4[av]|manifest|map|mp4|oex|og[agv]|opus|otf|pdf|png|rdf|rss|safariextz|svgz?|swf|topojson|tt[cf]|txt|vcard|vcf|vtt|webapp|web[mp]|webmanifest|woff2?|xloc|xml|xpi)$">
        Header unset X-UA-Compatible
    </FilesMatch>

</IfModule>
```

Comment: How to do same in the Nginx server?

Answer (score 0):

**2023**

In newer version, please use https://github.com/graycoreio/magento2-cors

Maintainer of `splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests` already confirmed that he no longer maintains this module. Checkout here: https://github.com/splashlab/magento-2-cors-requests/issues/11